# fetch multiple value from same table (hirarical)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch value Rows from single table.I want to fetch sub_id for specific id.

I achieved my require ment in 2 query.I want to do it in single query.I want to display result  'Event,order history,Event Ticket,calander'.

[image]

```
$sql="select * from table1 where roles like %admin% and sub_id='0'"
$sql1=mysql_query($sql);
while($fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
{
  $id=$fet['id'];
  $query="select page_name from table1 where sub_id= '$id'";
  .. ..
}
```

Comment: If you already have the specific id why not just query for the subcategories?

Comment: Please explain your question.

Answer (score 1):

What you need are [subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html).

Basically, you would like to select some rows that match a criteria that is given by another query's result.

The example below should both resolve your issue and clarify the concept:

```
select
  page_name
from
  table1
where
  sub_id in (
    select 
      id
    from
      table1
    where
      roles like '%admin%'
      and sub_id = 0
  )
```

Comment: While this maybe can answer the question, it's better to provide some explanations about how this code help.